# Как разместить исполняемый код php на статичной странице WP?

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на WordPress. 
На главной странице index.php есть такой код, который как я понял, выводит все записи.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
            endif;
            ?>
```

Как мне его же разместить на определённой статичной странице?
Попробовал через [exec][/exec], страница грузится и выдаёт 504 ошибку..

Comment: 1. Не трогай файлы. 2. Используй плагины для вставки кода. 3. Учи матчасть https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Вы можете добавить новый шаблон для страницы и в него добавить нужный код [инструкция](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)